# Why repository "Get" and "GetAsync" methods throw EntityNotFoundException instead of returning null if the entity doesn't exists?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Using the module-zero-core-template (fully updated), I recently had problems when a user asked for account deletion (it was the first time), a lot of places in my code were getting the "User" entity using Repository.Get(TPrimaryKey id) or Repository.GetAsync(TPrimaryKey id):

```
var user = _userRepository.Get(model.UserId);
```

Until now I didn't realize it was throwing an exception when the entity doesn't exists, but I had to replace all the calls by (or the equivalent async):

```
var user = _userRepository.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == model.UserId);
```

My code wasn't made to handle such exception, but only a null value in return.

My questions are:

- Why an exception instead of a null value returned?
- Is there a way to modify this behavior?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Where is that repository coming from? Can you please provide that code?

Comment: It comes from there : private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

Comment: Okay but where is the implementation?

Comment: It comes from Abp.Domain.Repositories, public interface IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository, ITransientDependency where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>

Comment: you want null oriented programming, but this is an opinionated framework and Get() behaves as Single(). So if you want to code error tolerated, before using GET() use ANY() to check the existence of the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the implementation is doing it like [that](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/c64804aa17eecb0078d18dd79997eadb6d041113/src/Abp/Domain/Repositories/AbpRepositoryBase.cs#L78).

If you want to find an entity without the exception being thrown, you have to use the `FirstOrDefault(TPrimaryKey id)` [function](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Domain/Repositories/AbpRepositoryBase.cs#L107).

**Edit(explanation):**

Is like saying `Single(x => x.Id == 1)`. You are expecting a result, if it doesn't have that, it will throw an exception. That's why we have `SingleOrDefault(expr)` and `SingleOrDefault(expr)` or `FirstOrDefault(expr)` and `First(expr)`. Same principal involved

Comment: Thank you but I perfectly understand why it throws an exception, I would like to know why it has been preferred to return null, and if there's a simple way to re-implement it to return null, like the "FirstOrDefault" method

Comment: Is like saying `Single(x => x.Id == 1)`. You are expecting a result, if it doesn't have that, it will throw an exception. That's why we have `SingleOrDefault(expr)` and `Single(expr)` or `FirstOrDefault(expr)` and `First(expr)`. Same principal involved. I honestly didn't think you know that since you weren't able to explain where your repository implementation is coming from.